# devexpress treelist changing datasource

Tags: devexpress, treelist

I have a treelist and I populate it with data in the load event of the form, it works.

In another form, I can add new values to the underlying data source. Then, I show the form again, which contains the treelist. In the load event, I perform the new query, also the data is the newest and I set the datasource to this new data. But the treelist is showing incorrect data. Why?

What am I missing?

Comment: I had to refresh the datasource too. It seems, that simply assign the new datasource to the treelist control wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no example of the code you are using, I'd suggest to use [BeginUpdate()](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_BeginUpdatetopic) and [EndUpdate()](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_EndUpdatetopic) like this:

```
treeList.BeginUpdate();
treeList.DataSource = your data;
treeList.EndUpdate();
```

EndUpdate(): Unlocks the TreeList object after a call to the BeginUpdate method and causes an immediate visual update